# Percona xtradb cluster 1 node consuming memory

Tags: mysql, percona

I've installed percona xtradb cluster on 3 nodes and all is good until i noticed that 1 node is consuming memory much more the other nodes
So i decided to stop all traffic going to this nodes and check if the memory is going to be full again.
Node 1:
used memory 7517M

Node2:
used memory 2669M

Node3:
used memory 2574M

Also i noticed that on node 1 which consuming all the memory that innodb buffer pool is full even when its out of traffic.

What might be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of mysqldump cron.
It was working in the node that was consuming the memory, and the main reason was because database has 12G table. This table makes the server memory full when mysqldump start.